# Static "interface" of singleton class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

The word "interface" here does not refer to the C# keyword. If you know a better name for the method I'll describe in this question, please let me know.

---

I use a singleton in one of my program.
And while programming it, I just thought it would be great to have all the singleton's methods implemented in static as well, acting as an "interface" of the singleton.

The point would be to write

`int ret = MyClass.GetValue();`

instead of

`int ret = MyClass.singleton.GetValue();`

That's what I describe as being an "interface" of a singleton and here is how I would implement it.

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static MyClass singleton = null;

    private int theValue = 123;

    private int InstanceGetValue();
    {
        return theValue;
    }

    public static int GetValue()
    {
        if (singleton == null)
            return default(int);
        return singleton.InstanceGetValue();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (singleton == null)
            singleton = this;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (singleton == this)
            singleton = null;
    }
}
```

So my question is:

#### What am I missing that could explain why this is not common practice when using singletons?

It makes every call look much better and it is simple to implement! Why is this not the default way of using singletons?

---

This is Unity code but you might be able to answer my question even if you don't use Unity. Just so you know, OnEnable is automatically called when this object become active in this scene and OnDisable is called when your object become inactive.

Let's not talk about whether using singletons is a good practice in C# in this topic. A lot of great topic are already answering this question.

Comment: Because it makes no sense. A singleton shouldn't need to be a singleton if you mainly intend to put static methods on it. it should just be static then.
Additionally, `MonoBehavior` was intended *not* to function like a singleton. if there should be only one, there should be only one object in your scene implementing it.

Comment: A singleton is instantiated only once through out the application. A static class is not. That is the difference. First, get clarity on whether you want singleton or static class

Comment: As I said, the value can't be static, the singleton is intended to change as the Unity scene does, so the singleton refers to a different object depending on the scene you're in. The value can't be static

Comment: So, er, it's not a singleton then?

Comment: I mean there is always one and only one object of this type per scene.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is a mess imho. you say "Let's not talk about whether using singletons is a good practice in C# in this topic.". whether or not using singletons is a good practice in general depends on the situation. Your `MonoBehavior` is also allowed to have static properties, so the need for this discussion is moot without knowing what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Does the singleton class inherit from `MonoBehavior`? The example in your question does not but this matters in order to answer the question properly. Also, why do you need singleton if there is only one type of that object?

Comment: If you need one object per scene, then do that instead. Why get into whether singletons are a good idea at all? Just keep the object as a property of your scene.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to clarify why it can't be a static value.

Comment: Also, nobody is asking for it to be static either...

Comment: *I'll try to clarify why it can't be a static value* - this will also respond to your own question. If it can't be static then it makes no sense to create static wrapper methods around it.

Comment: Your current implementation is not a singleton. You have a public constructor for starters. Also there is no execution path that will initialize the singleton static.

Comment: I think you're right Reasurria, what I'm doing here might not be called a singleton as it indeed doesn't match every criteria of a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it seems you're doing here is trying to write an adapter to allow for accessing the singleton. If you look at the Wikipedia page on the Singleton pattern you'll note that the implementation details around it specifies two requisites.

- ensure that only one instance of the singleton class ever exists
- provide *global access* to that instance

What you're trying to do here is hiding that global access which brings me to believe that you're trying to hide the global access point or just plain want to write less code by excluding the singleton call from the following: `MyClass.singleton.GetValue();`

I think the main question you'd have to ask yourself here is which of the two your trying to achieve. If you're trying to hide the global access point I'd suggest looking at why you're using a singleton in the first place, but if you're trying to write less code I'd rather question why you're trying to write less code and if you're not using some hard to read coding practices.

EDIT: I understand why you'd only want one instance in the scene, but I'd rather just take full responsibility of managing that lifecycle instead of just trying to leverage the singleton pattern for this.